# How to make a virtual NIC that has its own MAC and IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge

On Ubuntu, I need to make it seem like there are multiple, independent machines on a real network. This needs to be done without creating any additional VMs. At first, I thought of IP address aliasing, which kinda worked.
For example, my machine's adapter is named enp0s3 and it has an IP address of 10.0.2.14. I want other machines to see an additional machine on the network at 10.0.2.15. I used the below command to achieve that:

```
sudo ip a add 10.0.2.15/24 dev enp0s3
```

This works great, but the mac addresses for 10.0.2.14 and .15 are the same, which is not acceptable.

I tried simply changing the mac address, but that changes it for both .14 and .15.

What's the solution? I know it is possible because if I add an additional VirtualBox network adapter it has its own IP and mac address. I can't use that solution because I need to emulate so many machines (50+).

The closest answer I found was this [Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/create-virtual-network-adapter-with-own-mac-and-ip).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple [network namespaces](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/), each with their own ip address, and connect them together any way you want.

For example, let's say we want to simulate three nodes sharing a
private network. First we create a bridge device that will represent
the network:

```
ip link add name br-net0 type bridge
ip addr add 192.168.13.1/24 dev br-net0
ip link set br-net0 up
```

Which gets us:

```
# ip addr show br-net0
3: br-net0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:06:b9:b4:e9:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.68.13.1/24 scope global br-net0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Next, we'll create network namespaces to represent out fake machines:

```
# ip netns add node0
# ip netns add node1
# ip netns add node2
```

Next, we create three [veth pairs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html) that we'll use to connect our namespaces to the bridge:

```
ip link add name node0-ext type veth peer name node0-int netns node0
ip link add name node1-ext type veth peer name node1-int netns node1
ip link add name node2-ext type veth peer name node2-int netns node2
```

Each of these commands creates a `veth` pair, and puts one end of the
pair in the named network namespace. We need to connect the "outside"
end of each pair to our bridge:

```
ip link set master br-net0 dev node0-ext
ip link set master br-net0 dev node1-ext
ip link set master br-net0 dev node2-ext
```

Finally, we need to (a) assign addresses to our virtual nodes:

```
ip netns exec node0 ip addr add 192.168.13.10/24 dev node0-int
ip netns exec node1 ip addr add 192.168.13.11/24 dev node1-int
ip netns exec node2 ip addr add 192.168.13.12/24 dev node2-int
```

The `ip netns exec` command lets us run commands inside a network namespace (you can also do this using `nsenter`).

And (b) bring up all the interfaces:

```
for node in 0 1 2; do
  ip link set node${node}-ext up
  ip netns exec node${node} ip link set node${node}-int up
done
```

---

Now, we have three virtual nodes, each with a unique ip address and
MAC address:

```
# ping -c 1 192.168.13.10
PING 192.168.13.10 (192.168.13.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.13.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

--- 192.168.13.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.054/0.054/0.054/0.000 ms
# arp -an
? (192.168.122.1) at 52:54:00:90:73:ca [ether] on eth0
? (192.168.13.11) at ba:0b:4b:ed:e4:bb [ether] on br-net0
? (192.168.13.12) at da:38:38:32:29:17 [ether] on br-net0
? (192.168.13.10) at 56:ad:09:af:46:1f [ether] on br-net0
```

---

[Mininet](http://mininet.org/) is a great tool for automating this sort of setup.

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted the nodes to be on my actual network (not a private one)?

Comment: Put them on a bridge that is shared by your physical NIC (and assign addresses from the appropriate network range).

Comment: What would be the command to create that bridge? Would it be using bridge-utils?